# Reset Password - change from name and email address. It stucks at admin. Want to change it to info

Tags: password, reset

At the admin dashboard of my wordpress under wordpress settings > general my admin email is set as info@mydomain.com

Here is my issue. When a customer wants to reset her or his password automated mail is sending from admin@www.mydomain.com instead of the admin email I setup at the settings > general

Basically I want to change from email address from admin@www.domain.com to info@mydomain.com for automated reset password emails

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange! Sorry you got downvoted. But unfortunately stating just facts makes your question way too broad. Please update your question to include your previous attempts; to share a detailed and narrowly-scoped problem and where exactly you are stuck right now. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.1/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L320), WordPress will use `WordPress` as sender name and `wordpress@<SITENAME>` as sender email, if these params were note passed to `wp_mail`.

You can use [`wp_mail_from`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from) and [`wp_mail_from_name`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name) filters to modify these values though.

So if you want to change the sender e-mail address, just use this code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', function( $email ) {
    return 'info@mydomain.com';
});
```

PS. But `admin@www.mydomain.com` is not a default email address that should be used, so maybe one of your plugins/theme is already changing that.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Didn't work though. Probably you are right about plugins/theme warning. I checked some plugins would have something to do with that but couldn't find anyting. I will continue to search though. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Papalino what have you done with that code?